# Batch model matrixes to single Uniform Buffer Object

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I've decided to take a look at uniform buffer objects. But i am not sure when and when not use it.

I have tried to batch all models transformations into single array that i would send to the shader at once. But it has it's consequences. I have to also send to shader id for every vertex to match those transformations.

So my question is: Is it worth? Or should i prefer in that particular case to use regular glUniform calls?

Below is my shader program.

```c
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in int id;

layout (std140) uniform scene_data
{
    mat4 ViewProjectionMatrix;
    mat4 ModelMatrix[128];
};


void main()
{
    gl_Position = ViewProjectionMatrix * ModelMatrix[id] * vec4(position,1.0);  


}
```

Here is how i create Uniform Buffer Object:

```cpp
Dot::UniformBuffer::UniformBuffer(const void*data, unsigned int size, unsigned int index)
    :m_Index(index),m_size(size)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_UBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, m_UBO);
    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, size, data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, index, m_UBO);  
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);

}

Dot::UniformBuffer::~UniformBuffer()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_UBO);
}


void Dot::UniformBuffer::Update(const void* data)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, m_UBO);
    GLvoid* p = glMapBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
    memcpy(p, data, m_size);
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything has its tradeoffs, and would require performance measurements to verify.

Think of `glUniform` as pass-by-value, whereas UBO is pass-by-reference.  Except, there is [usually] no perf penalty in the GPU shader code for additional indirection to the UBO.

UBOs' main benefit is reducing CPU overhead at the "bind" stage, since all the values are already written to memory. A render can prepare many UBOs up front at loading time (one UBO per "state vector") to avoid having to transfer the data during the main rendering loop.  Typically you don't want to modify a UBO in-place in your renderer, because the `glMapBuffer` will wait for previous draws that are using that UBO to complete.

In this particular example, the shader is performing an "indexed constant lookup" using the input attribute `id`, which is slower than a uniform constant lookup.

Other considerations:

- `layout (location = 1) in int id;` requires the CPU to prepare an additional vertex buffer and index buffer.  This may also imply making data copies of the raw geometry, which is more CPU and memory intensive.
- `glDrawArraysInstanced` or `glDrawElementsInstanced` can let OpenGL generate the `id` for you instead.  From the shader, use `gl_InstanceID`.  Removes the need for additional vertex buffers.  That would be similar to https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing
- `glUniform` will cause the data to be transferred from application code --> driver --> GPU on every call.
- UBO requires more object management and planning, but usually converges on the fastest performing renderer.  Vulkan and D3D12 support only UBO style programming.

Comment: I was planning to send id in single VBO with vertices and other data , so i would not create new VBO, also i would update matrices in UBO once per frame at the end of rendering stage...so i wonder if it is more efficient to update single UBO for many objects , or update uniform multiple times.

Comment: If  prebaking the `id` into the VBO data is not a burden, then the only minor concern would be the indexed constant lookup in the shader (ModelMatrix[id] is using per-thread id).  If the vertices are grouped by id, it will tend to be uniform -> also good.
Updating UBO per frame may still cause undesired CPU/GPU sync, since OpenGL establishes a "software/hardware pipeline" like    [CPU] render thread --> [CPU] driver thread --> GPU.  The Map call creates an interlock.